# React Native SVG error- Unable to resolve svg

Tags: react-native, svg

```
import CheckboxUnchecked from '../assets/checkbox-unchecked.svg'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT0dR.png)

I install react-native-svg and react-native-svg-trasformer.

and use SVG above on...

but this ERROR bother me please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufy7A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NS0R.png)

++ my package.json is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t38hh.png)

my metro.config.js is here

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
  };

  return config;
})();
```

Comment: It's a typo: your file is called checkbox-uchecked.svg, (missing the "n" in unchecked) and you're importing checkbox-unchecked.svg

Comment: Please don't post images as text. Text should be included as text in the question.

Comment: thank comment. i am not skilled this page Sorry.
and i update typo, but my error isn't resolved